# How to create a division of colour in a PDF using PDFBox surrounding text without knowing the coordinates of the text?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to create a comment box using PDFBox. I won't be aware of the coordinates of the text. How do I create a division of color surrounding the text without knowing the coordinates?

I have found how to create a division of color by using the coordinates using AddRect function. I need to do it without knowing the coordinates.

Expected output:
[image: Expected output]

I want the output to look like the comment boxes present in the output of this image I have attached

Comment: There is no HTML code. Just the name of a file. And what is a "division of color"?

Comment: *"I need to do it without knowing the coordinates."* - That's the wrong approach. To draw a rectangle, you need to know the coordinates. So you don't *need to do it without knowing the coordinates* but instead you *need to determine the coordinates.* As you don't explain how the text comes into the document (Do you add it? Is it there already? Is it actual text or merely an image there-of? If it's already there, how to recognize it? ...), we hardly can help you in more detail.

Comment: I have added the image of the expected output @Tilman Hausherr.

Comment: I'm a beginner to PDFBox  @mkl . I don't know its capabilities well. The text I need to add comes from a string format . It is an actual text . In the image I posted, I need to create a comment box just like the html one,with the comment below the photo,name and date.

Comment: As you add the text, you *do* know its coordinates. After all you add it at coordinates! The only problem may be that you probably want to first draw the rectangle and then draw the text on that rectangle. But you can still first make a dry run adding the text to determine the coordinates, then draw the rectangle, then actually add the text at the predetermined coordinates. Or you can add the rectangle afterwards using a different blend mode to have the text underneath shine through the color.